How can I embed an X window in a perl/Tk notebook widget?
I found an example of how to embed an arbitrary X application window in a Perl/Tk Notebook widget.  However, I am unable to make it work. Specifically, the call to X->ReparentWindow does not work.  When called, the xterm application should have moved from displaying in a separate window managed by the window manager to displaying inside the notebook tab in the perl/Tk application.
I've extracted the relevant code into the example below, which assumes a window named xterm is already running.  When this runs, the xterm window is not embedded inside the notebook tab.  It remains a separate window.  I have confirmed that the get_window_by_name function finds the named window via its "class".  The use of xterm is just an example.  I need to reparent windows from any application.
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Tk;
use X11::Protocol;
use Tk::NoteBook;
use Data::Dumper;
my $X        = X11::Protocol->new();
my $mw       = MainWindow->new();
my $topframe = $mw->Frame()->pack(-side => 'top');
my $notebook = $topframe->NoteBook()->pack;
my $tab      = $notebook->add("example", -label => "Example");
my $pid;

unless ($pid = fork) { exec("xterm"); }

if ($pid) { sleep(3); grab_it("xterm", $tab); MainLoop(); }

sub grab_it
{
   my $winname = shift;
   my $tab     = shift;
   my $x_window_id;

   $x_window_id = get_window_by_name($winname);
   if (!$x_window_id) { exit(1) }

   $tab->update;
   $X->ReparentWindow($x_window_id, oct($tab->id), 0, 0);
}

sub get_window_by_name
{
   _get_window_by_name($X->{'root'}, $_[0]);
}

sub _get_window_by_name
{
   my ($root, $searchname) = @_;
   my (undef, undef, @new_kids) = $X->QueryTree($root);
   foreach my $k (@new_kids)
   {
      my ($atomnr) = grep { $X->GetAtomName($_) eq "WM_CLASS" } $X->ListProperties($k);
      if (defined $atomnr)
      {
         my ($class, $name) = split(/\0/, ($X->GetProperty($k, $atomnr, "AnyPropertyType", 0, 256, 0))[0]);
         if ($class =~ $searchname)
         {
            return $k;
         }
      }
      my $ret = _get_window_by_name($k, $searchname);
      if (defined $ret)
      {
         return $ret;
      }
   }
   undef;
}


"I need to reparent windows from any application." Maybe that is not supported by the X server? Maybe only applications that allow specifying a parent window id (like xterm) can be reparented? If you could find any examples that indicates otherwise it would be great. Then, we know at least that it is possible.

X11 window managers work by re-parenting top level application windows into a frame generated by the window manager (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-parenting_window_manager).  Re-parenting is initiated by the WM when you open a new application window.  A window manager is just another X11 application whose main job happens to be to provide window frames for windows produced by other applications.  I want Perl to do the same thing the window manager does. We know it's possible, because the xterm can re-parent itself into the tab (https://github.com/joejulian/xterm/blob/master/misc.c#L5819).

I downloaded the X11::Protocol tarball from CPAN and it failed its selftest quite early, but that may be my environment.

I was not able to get X11::Protocol's reparent window to work. Instead try to give the window id directly to xterm using the -into option. Also, create a container frame within the notebook that allows embedding:
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new();
$mw->title("XTerm Embedded in Tk");

my $notebook = $mw->NoteBook()->pack(-expand => 1, -fill => 'both');
my $tab = $notebook->add("example", -label => "Example");

# Create a frame within the tab to serve as a container
my $embed_frame = $tab->Frame(
    -container => 1,          # Set the frame as a container
    -width     => 600,
    -height    => 400,
)->pack(-expand => 1, -fill => 'both');

# Ensure the frame is realized and has a window ID
$embed_frame->update();

my $window_id = $embed_frame->id;
my $pid = fork();
if (not defined $pid) {
    die "Cannot fork: $!";
} elsif ($pid == 0) {
    # Child process
    exec("xterm", "-into", $window_id, "-geometry", "80x24") or die "Cannot exec xterm: $!";
    exit(0);
}

# Start the Tk event loop
MainLoop();
 


The use of xterm was just an example.  I need to reparent windows generated by any application, even those that don't support -into.  Thanks for the suggestion.
